# My portfolio site crashes IE 7 and IE 6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

My portfolio site www.jonathanbranthwaite.co.uk uses heavy JQuery - sliding carousel and lightbox navigation. It works fine in Firefox and Safari, and from what I gather in IE 8.

Does anyone know if the code is incorrect or if there is something making it crash, or is this just because of alot of JQuery.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Jonathan

Comment: This is a pretty general question.  Have you tried narrowing down the crash behavior to a simple case by simplifying a page that's crashing as far as possible?  You will get better results that way.  Also I suggest as a general practice checking your work in all common browsers as you go to avoid this type of surprise at the end of a project.

Comment: Please consider running IE in the debugger and getting a stack.

Answer (score 2):

It is crashing after it has loaded all the images.  At this point one of the Javascript functions is being called and causing an error in the HTTP library.  This most likely is because an HTTP call is being made behind the scenes.  Try removing each library in turn until you find the one causing the error, and then determine if you really need it.

The site doesn't look too bad with each profile being listed down the page, except it takes a really long time for me to load the page, and I have quite a fast connection here.